# What outperforms in code size: compilers or interpreters?

Tags: compilation, interpreter

Which code tends to be smaller?

1. Real machine code (Ada, C, C++, Fortran, etc.)
2. Pseudocode generated by interpreters or pseudocode compilers (Java, Python, Perl, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compact code representation currently known is the [indirect threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) used by some Forth implementations. It's in between fixed bytecode formats and the machine code.

But it is hard to generate a sane, compact Forth code out of the alien source languages, so for the best results you have to code in Forth or another language with a similar approach to abstractions straight away.

A threaded code generated from something like C or Java is much harder to compactify, although there are some interesting techniques. The resulting code, of course, will still be smaller than a machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago MS give MSVC++ version (non .NET, that was older times) with specific p-code generation, with evangelism that is smaller than x386 code. Idea has no direct continuation. Later was Sun Java, MS Java evolving into J#, then .NET